# Regex matching classes in className of a React/jsx element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, jsx

The following is a snippet of my React component

```js
<div className="grid lg:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-1 lg:gap-x-5">
  <article className={`${index > 0 ? 'border-t lg:border-t-0 xl:border-t border-gray-300/70' : ''} py-8 sm:flex xl:items-center lg:flex-col xl:flex-row`}>
    ...
  </article>
</div>
```

I need to get all of the classes that are in the component. I was able to match the classes within `className="grid lg:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-1 lg:gap-x-5"` with the following regex:

```js
/(?<=className=")(.*)(?=")/g
```

However, I can't figure out how to match the classes for

```js
className={`${index > 0 ? 'border-t lg:border-t-0 xl:border-t border-gray-300/70' : 'text-gray-900'} py-8 sm:flex xl:items-center lg:flex-col xl:flex-row`}
```

For example, I need to match `"border-t lg:border-t-0 xl:border-t border-gray-300/70 text-gray-900 py-8 sm:flex xl:items-center lg:flex-col xl:flex-row"` in the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this combination of 3 regex:

#### Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  text = "<div className=\"grid lg:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-1 lg:gap-x-5\">\
            <article className={`${index > 0 ? 'border-t lg:border-t-0 xl:border-t border-gray-300/70' : 'text-gray-900'} py-8 sm:flex xl:items-center lg:flex-col xl:flex-row` }\
              ...\
            </article>\
          </div>";

  console.log(text.match(/(?<=\?\s?')([^']*)(?='(\s?:|\s?}))|(?<=}\s?)([^`]*)(?=`\s?})/g).join(' '))
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- You might need to add `article className` checks before the regex below if you only need the classNames inside an article tag as the regex below might pick up other classes if it in between single quotes (`''`).

Comment: Thanks alot! It took me a while to understand the regex, but I finally got it. This mostly worked. It was only missing the `text-gray-900` in the other ternary option, but I managed to get it by adding this regex: `/(?<=className\s*=\s*{.*\?\s?'[^']*'\s*:\s?')([^']*)/g`. So in total its a combination of 4 regex.

Comment: Good job understanding it. I haven't provided any explanation since when I saw your regex, you're already using lookaheads so I assumed that you know how to understand this at least.